# How to save / get a value with the redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, web3js

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I was hoping you could help me with the following logic. I would like to return from a custom-built hook the last item the user selected in a onClick function.

```
const useActiveWeb3React = (): Web3ReactContextInterface<Web3Provider> => {
  const { chainId, account, ...web3React } = useWeb3React()
  const { solanaAccount, solanaChainId } = useSolanaWeb3React()

  const activeChain = "if the user's last selected chain is Solana" ? solanaChainId : chainId
  const activeAccount = activeChain === ChainId.SOLANA ? solanaAccount : account
  return { chainId: activeChain, account: activeAccount, ...web3React }
}
```

OnClick handler that would send a network change request to either MetaMask or Phantom Wallet when user selects one of the chains.

```
const handleSelection = (network: ChainId) => {
    onDismiss()
    onNetworkSelect(network)
  }
```

What I would like to accomplish is that if the user selected in the app `ChainId.SOLANA` I would like to update `activeChain` variable in the `useActiveWeb3React` hook so that the whole app also knows user now wants to be on Solana. And then if the user switches back to `Ethereum` I want to update the `activeChain` to reflect the users last selection. Also I would like to stay at that chain if user refreshes the app.

I have access to redux store in the app.

How would you do it?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You need three different things.

- Save a value inside the state
- Get a value inside the state
- Persit the state (so when user refresh the page you still have this information)

## How to save a value in the redux store ?

To avoid boilerplate redux team recommend to use [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) as the standard approach.

You can create a part of the state of your app with [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice)
This will help you to create actions creator and reducers

`userWallet.slice.ts`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface UserWalletState {
  chainId: ChainId | null
}

const initialState = { chainId: null }

const userWalletSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userWallet',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setChainId(state, action: PayloadAction<ChainId>) {
      state.chainId = action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const { setChainId } = userWalletSlice.actions
export default userWalletSlice.reducer
```

We create a slice named: `userWalletSlice` and we export the generated reducer, don't forget to add it as your reducers now:

`rootReducer.ts`

```js
import userWalletReducer from './userWallet.slice.ts'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({ userWallet: userWalletReducer })
```

When create this reducer inside `userWallet.slice.ts`:

```js
    setChainId(state, action: PayloadAction<ChainId>) {
      state.chainId = action.payload
    },
```

Every time we dispatch the action `setChainId`. This will take the payload and update `state.chainId`.

When we create `setChainId` reducer this will automatically create an action creator that you can export.

```js
export const { setChainId } = userWalletSlice.actions
```

You'll be able to dispatch it like this:

```
dispatch(setChainId(chainId))
```

Then inside your callback you can just do:

```
const handleSelection = (network: ChainId) => {
    onDismiss();
    dispatch(setChainId(network));
}
```

Now that you can put this chainId into your state, you need to retrieve automatically when it change.

## How to get a value from redux store ?

To get values inside the store we use selectors.

You can use [`createSelector`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) to create a memoized selector.

`userWallet.selector.ts`

```js
export const userWalletSelector = (state: AppState) => state.userWallet;

export const chainIdSelector = createSelector(userWalletSelector, userWallet => userWallet.chainId)
```

So now inside your custom hook you can get this value with the following line.

```js
const activeChain = useSelector(chainIdSelector);
```

## How to persist redux state to retrieve it when I refresh a page ?

There are multiple way to persist state of you app. For your kind of information like `chainId` you can use tool like [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save part of your state inside the local storage for example

Comment: Great Answer Julien! Thanks for the time answering it. Would you also have an idea if this is doable without Redux? Or rather I should stick to redux in such a case since I am going to update the store at least from 3 different handlers?